# Qt application interact with python 2.7

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, qt, pyqt

We have a large library and utility tools written in Python 2.7. And we need to create a GUI application that uses these python library and tools. So I'm looking for a solution that can easily interact between the GUI app and our python code base.
Requirements:

1. cross-platform: Linux, Windows;
2. these programming languages are preferred: C++, C#, Python.
   Performance is not very essential. The key is to quickly develop the
   GUI application;

I know that PyQt can be a good choice but what concerned me is - if we are to develop the GUI in Qt C++, interact with Python may not as easy as the other way round, i.e. python code can easily use Qt library because of PyQt but C++ code does not have something similar. When we have controls made in Qt C++, it would not be straightforward to use them in python.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: If your codebase is in python, why would you write your GUI code in C++?  Why not just write the GUI in python (ie. pyqt) as well?

Comment: If you want to make your Qt C++ extensions accessible to python, wrap them using [sip](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/) (i.e. the same tool that is used by pyqt).

Comment: @BrendanAbel, because it is possible that some of the components of the GUI app will be written in C++, esp. some 3rd party Qt controls, for instance.

Comment: @ekhumoro, that's good to know. At least there is a way to do this, but ideally we would prefer a solution without this hassle. PyQt is the best solution I found so far, but it is possible that there are some better options that I am not aware of.